# Is it possible to do a full join with Typeorm?

Tags: typeorm

Is there a way to do a full join with Typeorm?

My current query looks like this:

```
this.myRepository.createQueryBuilder('myEntity')
```

I need to fetch all `myEntity` rows. Sometimes they are related to a `myRelatedEntity` row, in which case the data of the latter must be fetched too. Sometimes they are not related to a `myRelationEntity`, in which case I still need to fetch the `myEntity` row.

Apparently there is no other way to do what I need than with a FULL JOIN. However it seems like FULL JOINs are not available in Typeorm.

Is there any way I can reach my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I used query for that.

```
this.myRepository.query(`
    SELECT *
    FROM myEntity
    FULL JOIN otherEntity ON otherEntity.id = myEntity.fid
`);
```